# toggle colour of box in TableViewCell when swiped

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am created a task table view and I want the user to be able to swipe right if the job is complete and then swipe right again if the job is incomplete.

On the left of the cell I have a box which I am creating with a UIView that represents if the cell is complete or not.

I want to be able to toggle the colour of the box between green (complete) and red (incomplete) when the user swipes right each time.

I don't know the best way to achieve this? I have searched for the answer in stackOverflow and couldn't see any solutions to my problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

My View controller:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Tasks"
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tableView.register(jobCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)        
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return text.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator

        let task = text[indexPath.row]
        let detailTask = detailText[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = task
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = detailTask

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        if jobComplete == ["true"] {
            let jobUncompleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Uncomplete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
                print("Job Complete")
                success(true)
            })

            //jobComplete = false
            jobUncompleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0)
            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [jobUncompleteAction])
        } else {
            let jobCompleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Complete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
                print("Job Complete")
                success(true)
            })
            //jobComplete = true
            jobCompleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.61, blue:0.02, alpha:1.0)
            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [jobCompleteAction])
        }
    }

}
```

My tableViewCell:

```
    class jobCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.textLabel?.frame.origin.x = 20
        self.detailTextLabel?.frame.origin.x = 20
    }

    let jobCompleteBar: UIView = {
        let jobCompleteBar = UIView()
        jobCompleteBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0)
        jobCompleteBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return jobCompleteBar
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        addSubview(jobCompleteBar)

        jobCompleteBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        jobCompleteBar.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        jobCompleteBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3).isActive = true
        jobCompleteBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true        
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you take "JobCell" & "jobCell"?

Comment: Improve question. What do you mean by "cell is complete or not"? Give one scenario that you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry the code at the bottom of the view controller was old code. I have removed that now & also improved the question. Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: What is jobComplete? and where you declare?

Comment: I am using Firebase to declare this and it will be referencing the database. So JobComplete will be in my database. But for now I am trying to understand the basics of how to toggle the colour of a UIView without using Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First cast your cell in cellForRow function:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! jobCell
```

Declare one variable in jobCell

```
var jobStatus: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        //your color for complete/incomplete
        jobCompleteBar.backgroundColor = jobStatus ? .green : .red
    }
}
```

Change jobStatus value from leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! jobCell

    //Check condition and change value of jobStatus

    if jobComplete == ["true"] {
        let jobUncompleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Uncomplete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            print("Job Complete")
            success(true)

            self.jobComplete = false

        })

        jobUncompleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0)
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [jobUncompleteAction])
    } else {
        let jobCompleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Complete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            print("Job Complete")
            success(true)

            self.jobComplete = true
        })

        jobUncompleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.61, blue:0.02, alpha:1.0)
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [jobCompleteAction])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting this error **Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands** in my **leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt**, on the line: `cell.jobStatus = true/false`.

Comment: Great that is working now. However, when I slide the cell a fraction to the right it changes the colour instead of only changing the colour when it is fully swiped to the right. Is there a way around this?

Comment: then you need to trigger action in handler of UIContextualAction

Comment: That worked - I had to change `self.jobComplete = true` to `cell.jobStatus = false`. I have one more question. I seemed to have lost my background colour of the UIContextualAction now it is inside the handler.

Comment: reverse the color

Comment: Im not getting any colour on the UIContextualAction at all though. It is grey.

Comment: move background color line before return. See updated answer

Comment: Perfect! Thank you